# R package "mpmi" to calculate the mutual information between two set of continuous variables

Tags: r, kernel-density, information-theory

I try to use the package mpmi to calculate the mutual information between two set of continuous variables. I am confused of the source code put on GutHub: https://github.com/cran/mpmi/blob/master/src/cminjk.f95

```
ans = ans + log(s12(i) / (s1(i) * s2(i)))

end do

ans = ans / lv + log(dble(lv))
```

The s12 seems like the `p(x,y)`, and s1,s2 seems like the `p(x),p(y)`.
Why not multiply the `p(x,y)` before `log(s12(i) / (s1(i) * s2(i)))`, for the formula to calculate MI is `p(x,y)*log(p(x,y)/(p(x)p(y)))`

And why there is `ans = ans / lv + log(dble(lv))` after finishing the summation?

Comment: I think these questions would be better addressed at the package creator/maintainer.

Comment: I have contacted the maintainer but does not receive the reply yet.

Answer (score 1):

Care with this reference: "Fast calculation of pairwise mutual information for gene regulatory network reconstruction"

This strategy assumes that each of the two random variables follow a normal distribution. Except if you know with certainty that both variables follow a normal distribution,I suggest the use of packages free of any distribution assumption. I recommend the R package "minerva". Just requires specify MIC(X,Y)$MIC.

Answer (score 0):

See reference "Fast calculation of pairwise mutual information for gene
regulatory network reconstruction"